# After 16 LTS update I can no longer see drives

Tags: 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16 LTS about two months ago on a custom built desktop, and it has been great. I did an update, and now all of my three external drives, and both of my internal drives are no longer visible. When I boot to windows they work fine.

Comment: Could you add the output of `lsblk -o +FSTYPE` with the drives connected?

Comment: Do the drives show up in the left pane of a Nautilus file manager window? If so, and you click on one, does it mount? Show us the output of **sudo more /etc/fstab** in terminal. Cheers, Al

Comment: The drives do not show on the left pane. I also scanned all of the menus for another way to get there. It might be that not all of the updates installed after downloading. I tried to update again, and all that happened was that  something installed.  After a reboot the drives showed up again. I thought that was the end of it, but after another reboot, they were gone again. Today they are back, and everything is fine. Now I am afraid to power off.

Comment: The drives do not show on the left pane. I also scanned all of the menus for another way to get there. It might be that not all of the updates installed after downloading. I tried to update again, and all that happened was that  something installed.  After a reboot the drives showed up again. I thought that was the end of it, but after another reboot, they were gone again. Today they are back, and everything is fine. Now I am afraid to power off. In trying to get a result for what I was told to do in the terminal, I was unable to enter my password. No characters showed?